# Problems with apt-get upgrade(dpkg and bluez)

Tags: ubuntu

What is the most possible solution to my case when i try to do a apt upgrade
The output see below.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
linux-headers-generic-lts-wily linux-signed-generic-lts-wily
linux-signed-image-generic-lts-wily
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up bluez (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
reload: Unknown instance:
invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed.
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "start" failed.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez-alsa:amd64:
bluez-alsa:amd64 depends on bluez; however:
Package bluez is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package bluez-alsa:amd64 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-bluetooth:
gnome-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 4.36); however:
Package bluez is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package gnome-bluetooth (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-bluetooth:
indicator-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 4.36); however:
Package bluez is not configured yet.
indicator-bluetooth depends on gnome-bluetooth | ubuntu-system-settings
however:
      Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.
      Package ubuntu-system-settings is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package indicator-bluetooth (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-control-center:
unity-control-center depends on indicator-bluetooth; however:
Package indicator-bluetooth is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package unity-control-center (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-user-share:
gnome-user-share depends on gnome-bluetooth; however:
Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package gnome-user-share (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
ubuntu-desktop depends on unity-control-center; however:
Package unity-control-center is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-control-center-signon:
unity-control-center-signon depends on unity-control-center; however:
Package unity-control-center is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package unity-control-center-signon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of webaccounts-extension- common:
webaccounts-extension-common depends on unity-control-center-signon | gnome-control-center-signon; however:
Package unity-control-center-signon is not configured yet.
Package gnome-control-center-signon is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package webaccounts-extension-common (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xul-ext-webaccounts:
 xul-ext-webaccounts depends on webaccounts-extension-common (= 0.5-0ubuntu2.14.04.1); however:
 Package webaccounts-extension-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package xul-ext-webaccounts (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
     bluez
     bluez-alsa:amd64
     gnome-bluetooth
     indicator-bluetooth
     unity-control-center
     gnome-user-share
     ubuntu-desktop
     unity-control-center-signon
     webaccounts-extension-common
     xul-ext-webaccounts
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try following steps:

1. Clean package cache:

   sudo apt-get clean
2. Correct dependency problems:

   sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -f
3. Configure unconfigured packages:

   sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: sorry, sudo apt-get clean doesn't work.

Comment: @StevenHuang Can you post the error? Normally, the command does not output anything. Otherwise, you can omit it and start from step 2 and.