# Issue with dpkg and sudo apt-get update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, python

When I write `dpkg --configure -a` I got this errorr:

```
dpkg: error processing package python-numpy (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-pil:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-scipy:
 python-scipy depends on python-numpy (>= 1:1.13.1); however:
  Package python-numpy is not configured yet.
 python-scipy depends on python-numpy-abi9; however:
  Package python-numpy-abi9 is not installed.
  Package python-numpy which provides python-numpy-abi9 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-scipy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-matplotlib:
 python-matplotlib depends on python-numpy (>= 1:1.13.1); however:
  Package python-numpy is not configured yet.
 python-matplotlib depends on python-numpy-abi9; however:
  Package python-numpy-abi9 is not installed.
  Package python-numpy which provides python-numpy-abi9 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-matplotlib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-numpy
 python-pil:amd64
 python-scipy
 python-matplotlib
```

[I followed this](https://superuser.com/questions/1093913/problems-with-apt-get-upgradedpkg-and-bluez), but from  `sudo apt-get update` I got error:

```
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease           
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Fetched 88.7 kB in 1s (98.6 kB/s)                              
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f5953b88740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Please, do you have any ideas what might be wrong?

Originally, I tried to reinstall Python but couldn't because of the `<prefix>` issues (in the second error output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup your `status` file:

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bak
```

Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status` by removing `python-numpy`, `python-pil:amd64`, `python-scipy` and `python-matplotlib` with its descriptions, then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

To solve the following error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
```

Refer to [this Q/A on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292957/how-can-i-troubleshoot-python-could-not-find-platform-independent-libraries-pr)

Comment: This worked. I just add for any other newby:
1. don't try to remove those things via terminal - go to the folder and change it directly there (Use Ctrl+F).
Thank You. Now I can run sudo dpkg --configure -a without an error.

Comment: @MariaZelenayova I am glad that your problem has been solved, you are welcome.